# Prove uniform convergence of an integral on bounded interval

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Let $f:[a,b]\times [x_1,x_2]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. I want to prove that it is uniformly convergent on $[x_1,x_2]$. By uniform convergence I mean
$$\lim_{u\to a}\sup_{x\in[x_1,x_2]}\left|\int_a^uf(t,x) dt\right|=0$$
$$\lim_{u\to b}\sup_{x\in[x_1,x_2]}\left|\int_u^bf(t,x) dt\right|=0$$

And I have a question. Is this property true if the function is continuous with respect to both variables, but not necessarily continuous?

Comment: A function in more variables is continuous if and only if it is continuous componentwise.

Comment: I don't think so. Let $f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2} & , (x,y)\neq 0 \\ 0 & ,(x,y)=0 \end{cases}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $|f|$ is continuous on a compact domain, let $\max |f| = M < \infty$. Then
$$\sup_x \left| \int_a^u f(t,x) dt \right| \le \sup_x \int_a^u|f(t,x)| dt \le \sup_x \int_a^u M dt = M (u-a) \to 0$$
and similarly use the same argument for the other limit.

Comment: In particular the same argument applies for any bounded function.